# Современные стандарты безопасности для почтовых приложений

Tags: email, безопасность

При попытке отправки почты из мобильного приложения получаю `AuthenticationFailedException` и в почтовом ящике письмо, которое содержит уведомление о том, что

> Your account is currently not enabled to sign in from apps that do not
>   meet modern security standards

Эту проблему, конечно, можно решить включением опции "less secure sign in" в почтовом ящике, но мне стало интересно, какие именно "modern security standards"? Есть ли точный список требований этих "современных стандартов безопасности" для приложений почтовых клиентов?

Comment: Хотя бы TLS, возможно?

Comment: @andreymal, опция "mail.smtp.starttls.enable" имеет значение true в тот момент, когда приходит это исключение